# The import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, jackson

I am facing the error `The import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml cannot be resolved.
XmlMapper cannot be resolved to a type`
in the `import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.XmlMapper;`.

My pom :

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Is there a problem in the version? Other import of jackson core and databind seems to work completely fine. This happens in the case of xml only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old jar with different Maven coordinates.

Try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xml-databind</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
  <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and `import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;`

For more reference, visit: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml